# Flash-AS3: Elapsed months or days

Tags: actionscript-3, date, flash-cs5

I would like to know how to get the elapsed months or days in order to know if 2 years have elapsed.

I did test this:

```
var date1_ms:Number = 1375363246687;
var date2_ms:Date = new Date();
var dif:Number = getDif(date1_ms,date2_ms);

function getDif(date1:Number,date2:Date):int
{
    var one_day:Number = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
    var date2_ms:Number = date2.getTime();  
    var difference_ms:Number = Math.abs(date1_ms - date2_ms)    
    trace (difference_ms);
    return Math.round(difference_ms/one_day);
    trace (dif);
}
```

But I'm not getting the value of `dif`. How can I get it?

Note: The var `date1_ms` will be stored in a XML.
`date2_ms` must be the current date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trace call is after the function's return statement. It will never execute. You'll probably want to move it to the line below where you call `getDif`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Donald. With your help, this thing is working now.